# Is TelosB mote compatible with Contiki-OS?

Tags: contiki

I found `exp5438` and `z1` motes, which have `TI MSP430x` as a MCU, in [the Contiki code tree](http://www.contiki-os.org/hardware.html), and we know that `TI MSP430` is the [TelosB mote](http://www.willow.co.uk/TelosB_Datasheet.pdf)'s microcontroller.

I would like to know if TelosB motes are compatible with Contiki ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The telosB mote is compatible with Contiki OS, in fact I am using them with Contiki. To program them, in case you are using Instant Contiki, you will need to install the GCC for the MSP430 micro controller. You can use the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-msp430
```

On the other hand, I think to solve the problem of your answer I think you just need to be root. So try the next:

```
sudo -s
make TARGET=sky hello-world.upload
```

I hope that help you out.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

currently I am using telosb to run contiki applications. I followed the official site tutorial and apparently if u do make TARGET=sky it compiles the source files. However, doing `make TARGET=sky hello-world.upload` does not work. Shows

```
make sky-reset sky-upload

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/contiki-2.6/examples/hello-world'

make -k -j 1 sky-reset-sequence

make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/contiki-2.6/examples/hello-world'

Done

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/contiki-2.6/examples/hello-world'

make -j 1 sky-upload-sequence

make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/contiki-2.6/examples/hello-world'

Done

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/contiki-2.6/examples/hello-world'

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/contiki-2.6/examples/hello-world'

rm hello-world.ihex
```

which according to the official site tutorial means that the board is not connected. I am very certain it is connected. Also, make login never shows anything for me since the previous command didnt work.

Eventually, a friend of mine discovered a way to flash contiki applications into telosb. However, you need TinyOS development environment in your Instant Contiki. You can find information on setting up TinyOS environment in Ubuntu on [www.eetutorials.com](http://www.eetutorials.com).

This doesn't seem like a proper way of doing it but well so far it works for me when running simple applications

Step 1:

Compile your applications by doing:

```
make TARGET=sky application-name
```

Step 2:

```
msp430-objcopy application-name.sky -O ihex application-name.ihex

sudo tos-bsl --telosb -c /dev/ttyUSB0 -r -e -I -p application-name.ihex
```

However, make login still doesn't show anything hence I have been seeing my printf outputs
via Serial Port Terminal application which need to be installed. My guess is that contiki supports sky but not really for telosb? I am no expert and I can't tell the difference between the 2 boards. However, hope this information help and hope a contiki expert can further clarify on this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

telosb mote is the same as a tmote sky or sky. The name is all the same platform.

I dont know from which vendor you have the board, but they have to work.
I am also using sky motes with contiki and i had no complications from the beginning.

Try to use the code in the following site: [Unreadable output results when typing "make login"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221267/unreadable-output-results-when-typing-make-login)

This will print a message every second.

PS: Try to update your question if you found more information, dont add an answer since it confuses people.