# Unreadable output results when typing "make login"

Tags: contiki

I want to test the hello world application in a `z1 mote`. Unfortunately, when I try to visualize the results in the terminal using this command: `make z1-reset & make login`,
I always get an unreadable result:

> ����������������������������à������������������������������頲��

I run the test in Ubuntu 12.04 using contiki 2.7 and msp430-gcc 4.6.3
Are there any necessary drivers for zolertia `z1 motes` that I forgot to install?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the Z1 is already sending data over the USB port before the `make login` is finished and ready to receive, resulting in weird data. Try resetting the Z1 mote using a reset button or a on/off switch.

If that resets the `login` program, then you could try a LED example.

Or try below example that repeats the hello world message:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include <stdio.h> /* For printf() */

PROCESS(hello_world_process, "Hello world process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&hello_world_process);

PROCESS_THREAD(hello_world_process, ev, data)
{
static struct etimer et;

PROCESS_BEGIN();

printf("First Hello world\n");

while(1){

    //wait 1 second
    etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND);
    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));

    printf("Hello world\n\n");
}

PROCESS_END();
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not work for me. I suggest that there is  nothing wrong with the compiler or the program itself but the z1 platform. The fact is that I tried with another z1 mote and it works.
Thanks for your response anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a few weeks ago working on the Z1 ...what u should do is update the GCC-version to 4.7.0

You can follow these steps to upgrade the MSP430-gcc:

1. Update msp430 to version 4.7.0 follow  http://wiki.contiki-os.org/doku.php?id=msp430x
2. After finish install msp430 version 4.7.0, move folder mspgccx from /opt/tmp/ to /opt/
3. Run export PATH=/opt/mspgccx/bin:$PATH on terminal for temporary, but for permanent need to put in bash_rc or bash_profile.
4. Then can compile contiki code.

Someone shared it with me and it did work for me..hope it works for you =) Read the steps carefully, it is a little tricky. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I afraid that it's not the problem. Because I'm using instantcontiki 2.7 which has msp430-4.7 installed but the weird output still exists.